# Find the intersection of dict of dicts based on the rules in python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries as given below and want to find the intersection of dictionaries based on some logic.

```
dict1= {"1":{"score1": 1.099, "score2":0.45},
       "2": {"score2": 0.099, "score3":1.45},
       "3": {"score2": 10, "score3":10.45}}
dict2= {"1":{"score6": 1.099, "score2":0.45},
       "2": {"score2": 10, "score3":10.45},
       "4": {"score5": 8, "score8":15}}
```

I want to create the dictionary based on the given two dictionaries based on the below rules:

1.union of the two dicitonaries based on the outer key

2. if outer key is common in both the dictionaries then in the nested key-value pair show          only the common key with highest value across both the dictionaries.

````
result_dict = {"1":{"score2":0.45},
       "3": {"score2": 10, "score3":10.45},
       "2": {"score2": 10, "score3":10.45},
       "4": {"score5": 8, "score8":15}}```
````

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks for providing concrete examples of what your inputs are like and what you'd like the output to look like.

There may well be more efficient ways of doing this, but since there's no mention of any constraints on performance, my first instinct was to turn to Python's `set` operations to make things a little simpler:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

dict1 = {
    "1": {
        "score1": 1.099,
        "score2": 0.45
    },
    "2": {
        "score2": 0.099,
        "score3": 1.45
    },
    "3": {
        "score2": 10,
        "score3": 10.45
    }
}
dict2 = {
    "1": {
        "score6": 1.099,
        "score2": 0.45
    },
    "2": {
        "score2": 10,
        "score3": 10.45
    },
    "4": {
        "score5": 8,
        "score8": 15
    }
}

result_dict = {
    "1": {
        "score2": 0.45
    },
    "3": {
        "score2": 10,
        "score3": 10.45
    },
    "2": {
        "score2": 10,
        "score3": 10.45
    },
    "4": {
        "score5": 8,
        "score8": 15
    }
}


def weird_union(d1, d2):
    """Applies the logic in OP's question

    Args:
        d1 (dict): dict with one level of nested dicts as values
        d2 (dict): dict with one level of nested dicts as values

    Returns: dict

    """
    result = {}
    k1, k2 = set(d1.keys()), set(d2.keys())

    # no collisions-- easy case
    for k in k1.symmetric_difference(k2):
        result[k] = d1[k] if k in d1 else d2[k]

    # key appears in both dicts
    for k in k1.intersection(k2):
        _k1, _k2 = set(d1[k].keys()), set(d2[k].keys())
        result[k] = {
            key: max([d1[k][key], d2[k][key]])
            for key in _k1.intersection(_k2)
        }

    return result


test = weird_union(dict1, dict2)

assert result_dict == test
print('Test passed.')
```

The basic idea is to treat the disjoint and the intersection cases separately. Hope this helps.

**Update in response to comment:**

In the future, please provide this sort of context up front; an operation on two dictionaries is rather different than an operation on an arbitrary number of inputs.

Here's one way to do it:

```py
def invert_dicts(*dicts):
    """ Takes multiple dicts and returns a dict mapping
    key to dict index. E.g.,

    invert_dicts(
        {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        {'a': 3, 'c': 4}
    )

    returns

    {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [0], 'c': [1]}
    """
    key_map = {}
    for i, d in enumerate(dicts):
        for k in d.keys():
            key_map.setdefault(k, []).append(i)
    return key_map


def weird_n_union(*dicts):
    """Applies the logic in OP's question to an arbitrary number of inputs

    >>> weird_n_union(d1, d2, ..., dn)

    Args:
        *dicts (dict): dictionaries w/one level of nested dicts as values

    Returns: dict

    """
    result = {}

    # dict mapping key to list of dict index in `dicts` containing key
    key_map = invert_dicts(*dicts)

    for k in key_map:

        # no outer key collision
        if len(key_map[k]) == 1:
            result[k] = dicts[key_map[k][0]][k]
        # outer key collision
        else:
            # unclear what should happen in the case where:
            # - there is an outer key collision
            # - there are no shared sub-keys
            #
            # this implementation assumes that in that case, the value for k is {}
            result.setdefault(k, {})

            sub_dicts = tuple(dicts[i][k] for i in key_map[k])

            # map keys in `sub_dicts` to indices for `dicts` containing key
            sub_key_map = invert_dicts(*sub_dicts)

            # contains elements of (k, v), where k appears in > 1 sub-dicts
            shared_keys_only = filter(lambda kv: len(kv[1]) > 1,
                                      sub_key_map.items())

            # update result with the max value for each shared key
            for kv in shared_keys_only:
                max_ = max(((kv[0], sub_dicts[i][kv[0]]) for i in kv[1]),
                           key=lambda x: x[1])
                result[k].update({max_[0]: max_[1]})

    return result
```

Tried to annotate to make it a bit clear how things work. Hopefully this works for your use case.

Comment: Don't do this: `sorted(result_dict) == sorted(test)` first of all, that only compares *keys*, second of all, you don't need to sort anything, dictionary equality is defined independently of order, you just want `result_dict == test`

Comment: This is great! But I happen to find out the I want to do the same thing on 5 dictionaries,So can you please tell what changes I need to make?